# Method declaration in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Why are we declaring a method like

```
- (void) createBudget: (double) aBudget withExchangeRate: (float) anExchangeRate;
```

Why not like:

```
-(void) createBudget: (double) aBudget; -(void) withExchangeRate: (float) anExchangeRate;"
```

in Objective-C

What is the use of declaring a method in first way..?

Comment: In first way you declared method with two arguments, in second - two methods with one argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay you are misunderstanding the method and its parameters.

```
- (void) createBudget: (double) aBudget withExchangeRate: (float) anExchangeRate;
```

declares the `createBudget` method with two parameters (messages it can receive) `aBudget` and `anExchangeRate` .  Use would be:

```
  [createBudget 1000.00 withExchageRate: 1.5]
```

the second way is declaring two methods and while it may work it is a bit odd to have two methods when the idea is to create a budget with a declared exchange rate.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you already know that the 2nd way will create two methods with one argument while the first creates one method which two arguments. So your question comes down to why pass multiple arguments to a method. We do that because for the method in order to function correctly, needs **both** the arguments

Case in point: Consider an `NSMutableArray` object `mutableArray`

```
- (void)insertObject:(id)anObject atIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

If we call this method on mutableArray, we can insert anObject at index-index. See how this way of creating a method is weird at first but reads really well.

if we were to separate it to 2 methods

```
- (void)insertObject:(id)anObject;
- (void)atIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

It both cases we would know only what object to insert or where to insert. But never both which is what is required to insert properly.

Answer (score 0):

The first function is actually a function with two parameter.

```
- (void) createBudget: (double) aBudget withExchangeRate: (float) anExchangeRate;
```

you can also declare the above function as

```
- (void) createBudget: (double) aBudget:(float) anExchangeRate;
```

both will work fine but from the understanding point of view, from first declaration, a person can guess what this function is all about. he/she will directly say that this function takes a parameter- budget with exchange rate and perform operation on it.

where as in second declaration if we change the variable `aBudget` and `anExchangeRate` to something else then no one can make a guess what it gonna do.

Now for your second function:

`-(void) createBudget: (double) aBudget; -(void) withExchangeRate: (float) anExchangeRate;`

here you have created 2 functions i.e. `createBudget` and `withExchangeRate` not one.
so you will be calling these functions separately means when you will call `createBudget` you can only access `aBudget` not the `anExchangeRate` as it is defined in separate function.